# `rclcpp::Clock(RCL_ROS_TIME).now()` vs. `node_->get_clock()->now()`

Tags: ros, ros2, rclcpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is `rclcpp::Clock(RCL_ROS_TIME).now()` always the same as `node_->get_clock()->now()`?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/392066/%60rclcpp::clock(rcl_ros_time).now()%60-vs.-%60node_-%3Eget_clock()-%3Enow()%60/) by [galou](https://answers.ros.org/users/14171/galou/) on ROS Answers with karma: 265 on 2021-12-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well, it looks that the answer is NO. I had some issues with this and wasn't satisfied with the answer so I wrote a small node to test these clocks. The test is carried out with Galactic. The complete code can be found at https://github.com/galou/test_clock and the source is below

```
#include <chrono>
#include <string>

#include <rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp>

using namespace std::chrono_literals;

class TestClockNode : public rclcpp::Node
{
  public:

    TestClockNode(
        const std::string & node_name,
        const rclcpp::NodeOptions & options = rclcpp::NodeOptions()) :
      rclcpp::Node{node_name, options}
    {
      timer_ = create_wall_timer(1s, [this] () {timerCallback();});
    }

  private:

    rclcpp::TimerBase::SharedPtr timer_;
    void timerCallback()
    {
      RCLCPP_INFO_STREAM(get_logger(), "now(): " << now().seconds());
      RCLCPP_INFO_STREAM(get_logger(), "  rclcpp::Clock{}.now(): " << rclcpp::Clock{}.now().seconds());
      RCLCPP_INFO_STREAM(get_logger(), "  rclcpp::Clock{RCL_ROS_TIME}.now(): " << rclcpp::Clock{RCL_ROS_TIME}.now().seconds());
      RCLCPP_INFO_STREAM(get_logger(), "  rclcpp::Clock{RCL_SYSTEM_TIME}.now(): " << rclcpp::Clock{RCL_SYSTEM_TIME}.now().seconds());
      RCLCPP_INFO_STREAM(get_logger(), "  rclcpp::Clock{RCL_STEADY_TIME}.now(): " << rclcpp::Clock{RCL_STEADY_TIME}.now().seconds());
    }

};

int
main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
  rclcpp::init(argc, argv);

  auto node = std::make_shared<TestClockNode>("test_clock");
  if (node == nullptr)
  {
    return 1;
  }

  auto executor = rclcpp::executors::SingleThreadedExecutor{};
  executor.add_node(node);
  executor.spin();

  rclcpp::shutdown();

  return 0;
}
```

You need a running simulated time provider (i.e. a simulator) to test and you need to launch with

```
ros2 run test_clock test_clock --ros-args --param use_sim_time:=true --
```

Example of output:

```
[INFO] [1645622804.092181382] [test_clock]: now(): 2216.74
[INFO] [1645622804.092376229] [test_clock]:   rclcpp::Clock{}.now(): 1.64562e+09
[INFO] [1645622804.092445844] [test_clock]:   rclcpp::Clock{RCL_ROS_TIME}.now(): 1.64562e+09
[INFO] [1645622804.092512516] [test_clock]:   rclcpp::Clock{RCL_SYSTEM_TIME}.now(): 1.64562e+09
[INFO] [1645622804.092567862] [test_clock]:   rclcpp::Clock{RCL_STEADY_TIME}.now(): 199532
```

---

Originally posted by [galou](https://answers.ros.org/users/14171/galou/) with karma: 265 on 2022-02-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aprotyas](https://answers.ros.org/users/74476/aprotyas/) on 2022-02-27**:
I see the results, but looking at the source I'm really not sure why there would be a difference between the two. `rclcpp::Node` defaults to a clock of type `RCL_ROS_TIME`, and the `node_->now()` function simply delegates to the clock's `now()` function instead.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When `use_sim_time` is enabled, `RCL_ROS_TIME` type clock will use time source from topic `/clock`.

But we have to attach the `rcrclcpp::Clock(RCL_ROS_TIME)` to one ros node(and furthor one executor) to be able subscibe to topic `/clock` and update simulated time stored in RCL_ROS_TIME clock instance.
According to this understanding, we can also conclude that, as long as the attached node and executor is not `spin()`ing, the simulated clock won't be updated.

That's the behavior of `node_->get_clock()`.

A standalone `rcrclcpp::Clock(RCL_ROS_TIME)` have no way to subscribe to topic `/clock`, then as a fallback strategy, it will behave like a `RCL_SYSTEM_TIME` type clock.

---

Originally posted by [tsingakbar](https://answers.ros.org/users/118701/tsingakbar/) with karma: 26 on 2022-09-23

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1